# Преобразование из .py в .exe с изображением (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я преобразовываю из `.py` в `.exe` через `pyinstaller`, но задаюсь вопросом, как склеить скрипт с изображением в один исполняемый файл. В моем приложении задействована библиотека `tkinter`, в качестве изображения иконка, но после преобразования вылетает ошибка, что изображение не найдено

> wn_iconbitmap_tkinter.TclError: bitmap icon.ico not defined

P.s. возможно ли выполнить такое преобразование все-таки?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7674790/4279)